# PowerShell - What Feature names can I use on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: powershell

I'm authoring some PowerShell on a laptop in a coffee shop and I don't have a server to hand, and I need to know the Windows Feature names for use with DSC and `Install-WindowsFeature`.

Does anyone have a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example set taken from Windows Server 2012 R2 as of September 2016. Hope it helps.

```
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[ ] Active Directory Certificate Services               AD-Certificate                 Available
    [ ] Certification Authority                         ADCS-Cert-Authority            Available
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service       ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol            Available
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service              ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc            Available
    [ ] Certification Authority Web Enrollment          ADCS-Web-Enrollment            Available
    [ ] Network Device Enrollment Service               ADCS-Device-Enrollment         Available
    [ ] Online Responder                                ADCS-Online-Cert               Available
[ ] Active Directory Domain Services                    AD-Domain-Services             Available
[ ] Active Directory Federation Services                ADFS-Federation                Available
[ ] Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services     ADLDS                          Available
[ ] Active Directory Rights Management Services         ADRMS                          Available
    [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Server       ADRMS-Server                   Available
    [ ] Identity Federation Support                     ADRMS-Identity                 Available
[ ] Application Server                                  Application-Server             Available
    [ ] .NET Framework 4.5                              AS-NET-Framework               Available
    [ ] COM+ Network Access                             AS-Ent-Services                Available
    [ ] Distributed Transactions                        AS-Dist-Transaction            Available
        [ ] WS-Atomic Transactions                      AS-WS-Atomic                   Available
        [ ] Incoming Network Transactions               AS-Incoming-Trans              Available
        [ ] Outgoing Network Transactions               AS-Outgoing-Trans              Available
    [ ] TCP Port Sharing                                AS-TCP-Port-Sharing            Available
    [ ] Web Server (IIS) Support                        AS-Web-Support                 Available
    [ ] Windows Process Activation Service Support      AS-WAS-Support                 Available
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             AS-HTTP-Activation             Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Activation                  AS-MSMQ-Activation             Available
        [ ] Named Pipes Activation                      AS-Named-Pipes                 Available
        [ ] TCP Activation                              AS-TCP-Activation              Available
[ ] DHCP Server                                         DHCP                           Available
[ ] DNS Server                                          DNS                            Available
[ ] Fax Server                                          Fax                            Available
[X] File and Storage Services                           FileAndStorage-Services        Installed
    [ ] File and iSCSI Services                         File-Services                  Available
        [ ] File Server                                 FS-FileServer                  Available
        [ ] BranchCache for Network Files               FS-BranchCache                 Available
        [ ] Data Deduplication                          FS-Data-Deduplication          Available
        [ ] DFS Namespaces                              FS-DFS-Namespace               Available
        [ ] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication             Available
        [ ] File Server Resource Manager                FS-Resource-Manager            Available
        [ ] File Server VSS Agent Service               FS-VSS-Agent                   Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Server                         FS-iSCSITarget-Server          Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Storage Provider (VDS and V... iSCSITarget-VSS-VDS            Available
        [ ] Server for NFS                              FS-NFS-Service                 Available
        [ ] Work Folders                                FS-SyncShareService            Available
    [X] Storage Services                                Storage-Services               Installed
[ ] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V                        Available
[ ] Network Policy and Access Services                  NPAS                           Available
    [ ] Network Policy Server                           NPAS-Policy-Server             Available
    [ ] Health Registration Authority                   NPAS-Health                    Available
    [ ] Host Credential Authorization Protocol          NPAS-Host-Cred                 Available
[ ] Print and Document Services                         Print-Services                 Available
    [ ] Print Server                                    Print-Server                   Available
    [ ] Distributed Scan Server                         Print-Scan-Server              Available
    [ ] Internet Printing                               Print-Internet                 Available
    [ ] LPD Service                                     Print-LPD-Service              Available
[ ] Remote Access                                       RemoteAccess                   Available
    [ ] DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)                      DirectAccess-VPN               Available
    [ ] Routing                                         Routing                        Available
    [ ] Web Application Proxy                           Web-Application-Proxy          Available
[ ] Remote Desktop Services                             Remote-Desktop-Services        Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker                RDS-Connection-Broker          Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway                          RDS-Gateway                    Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing                        RDS-Licensing                  Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Session Host                     RDS-RD-Server                  Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Virtualization Host              RDS-Virtualization             Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Web Access                       RDS-Web-Access                 Available
[ ] Volume Activation Services                          VolumeActivation               Available
[ ] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server                     Available
    [ ] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer                  Available
        [ ] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http                Available
            [ ] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc                Available
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing               Available
            [ ] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors                Available
            [ ] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content             Available
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect              Available
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing             Available
        [ ] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health                     Available
            [ ] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging               Available
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging             Available
            [ ] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries              Available
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging               Available
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor            Available
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing               Available
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance                Available
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression           Available
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression            Available
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security                   Available
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering                  Available
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth                 Available
            [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support     Web-CertProvider               Available
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth                Available
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth                Available
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth                  Available
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security                Available
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth                   Available
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth               Available
        [ ] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev                    Available
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext                    Available
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 4.5                  Web-Net-Ext45                  Available
            [ ] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit                    Available
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP                        Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net                    Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 4.5                             Web-Asp-Net45                  Available
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI                        Available
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext                  Available
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter               Available
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes                   Available
            [ ] WebSocket Protocol                      Web-WebSockets                 Available
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server                 Available
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service                Available
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext                    Available
    [ ] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools                 Available
        [ ] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console               Available
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat                Available
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase                   Available
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console          Available
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting             Available
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI                        Available
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools            Available
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service               Available
[ ] Windows Deployment Services                         WDS                            Available
    [ ] Deployment Server                               WDS-Deployment                 Available
    [ ] Transport Server                                WDS-Transport                  Available
[ ] Windows Server Essentials Experience                ServerEssentialsRole           Available
[ ] Windows Server Update Services                      UpdateServices                 Available
    [ ] WID Database                                    UpdateServices-WidDB           Available
    [ ] WSUS Services                                   UpdateServices-Services        Available
    [ ] Database                                        UpdateServices-DB              Available
[ ] .NET Framework 3.5 Features                         NET-Framework-Features         Available
    [ ] .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)  NET-Framework-Core               Removed
    [ ] HTTP Activation                                 NET-HTTP-Activation            Available
    [ ] Non-HTTP Activation                             NET-Non-HTTP-Activ             Available
[X] .NET Framework 4.5 Features                         NET-Framework-45-Fea...        Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.5                              NET-Framework-45-Core          Installed
    [ ] ASP.NET 4.5                                     NET-Framework-45-ASPNET        Available
    [X] WCF Services                                    NET-WCF-Services45             Installed
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             NET-WCF-HTTP-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Message Queuing (MSMQ) Activation           NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Named Pipe Activation                       NET-WCF-Pipe-Activat...        Available
        [ ] TCP Activation                              NET-WCF-TCP-Activati...        Available
        [X] TCP Port Sharing                            NET-WCF-TCP-PortShar...        Installed
[ ] Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)      BITS                           Available
    [ ] IIS Server Extension                            BITS-IIS-Ext                   Available
    [ ] Compact Server                                  BITS-Compact-Server            Available
[X] BitLocker Drive Encryption                          BitLocker                      Installed
[ ] BitLocker Network Unlock                            BitLocker-NetworkUnlock        Available
[ ] BranchCache                                         BranchCache                    Available
[ ] Client for NFS                                      NFS-Client                     Available
[ ] Data Center Bridging                                Data-Center-Bridging           Available
[ ] Direct Play                                         Direct-Play                    Available
[X] Enhanced Storage                                    EnhancedStorage                Installed
[ ] Failover Clustering                                 Failover-Clustering            Available
[ ] Group Policy Management                             GPMC                           Available
[ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                               Web-WHC                        Available
[ ] Ink and Handwriting Services                        InkAndHandwritingSer...        Available
[ ] Internet Printing Client                            Internet-Print-Client          Available
[ ] IP Address Management (IPAM) Server                 IPAM                           Available
[ ] iSNS Server service                                 ISNS                           Available
[ ] LPR Port Monitor                                    LPR-Port-Monitor               Available
[ ] Management OData IIS Extension                      ManagementOdata                Available
[ ] Media Foundation                                    Server-Media-Foundation        Available
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                           Available
    [ ] Message Queuing Services                        MSMQ-Services                  Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Server                      MSMQ-Server                    Available
        [ ] Directory Service Integration               MSMQ-Directory                 Available
        [ ] HTTP Support                                MSMQ-HTTP-Support              Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Triggers                    MSMQ-Triggers                  Available
        [ ] Multicasting Support                        MSMQ-Multicasting              Available
        [ ] Routing Service                             MSMQ-Routing                   Available
    [ ] Message Queuing DCOM Proxy                      MSMQ-DCOM                      Available
[ ] Multipath I/O                                       Multipath-IO                   Available
[ ] Network Load Balancing                              NLB                            Available
[ ] Peer Name Resolution Protocol                       PNRP                           Available
[ ] Quality Windows Audio Video Experience              qWave                          Available
[ ] RAS Connection Manager Administration Kit (CMAK)    CMAK                           Available
[ ] Remote Assistance                                   Remote-Assistance              Available
[ ] Remote Differential Compression                     RDC                            Available
[ ] Remote Server Administration Tools                  RSAT                           Available
    [ ] Feature Administration Tools                    RSAT-Feature-Tools             Available
        [ ] SMTP Server Tools                           RSAT-SMTP                      Available
        [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Administratio... RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
            [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Tools        RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
            [ ] BitLocker Recovery Password Viewer      RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
        [ ] BITS Server Extensions Tools                RSAT-Bits-Server               Available
        [ ] Failover Clustering Tools                   RSAT-Clustering                Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Management Tools       RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt           Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Module for Windows ... RSAT-Clustering-Powe...        Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Automation Server      RSAT-Clustering-Auto...        Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Command Interface      RSAT-Clustering-CmdI...        Available
        [ ] IP Address Management (IPAM) Client         IPAM-Client-Feature            Available
        [ ] Network Load Balancing Tools                RSAT-NLB                       Available
        [ ] SNMP Tools                                  RSAT-SNMP                      Available
        [ ] WINS Server Tools                           RSAT-WINS                      Available
    [ ] Role Administration Tools                       RSAT-Role-Tools                Available
        [ ] AD DS and AD LDS Tools                      RSAT-AD-Tools                  Available
            [ ] Active Directory module for Windows ... RSAT-AD-PowerShell             Available
            [ ] AD DS Tools                             RSAT-ADDS                      Available
                [ ] Active Directory Administrative ... RSAT-AD-AdminCenter            Available
                [ ] AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line ... RSAT-ADDS-Tools                Available
                [ ] Server for NIS Tools [DEPRECATED]   RSAT-NIS                       Available
            [ ] AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools  RSAT-ADLDS                     Available
        [ ] Hyper-V Management Tools                    RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools             Available
            [ ] Hyper-V GUI Management Tools            Hyper-V-Tools                  Available
            [ ] Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell   Hyper-V-PowerShell             Available
        [ ] Remote Desktop Services Tools               RSAT-RDS-Tools                 Available
            [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway Tools            RSAT-RDS-Gateway               Available
            [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing Diagnoser T... RSAT-RDS-Licensing-D...        Available
            [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing Tools          RDS-Licensing-UI               Available
        [ ] Windows Server Update Services Tools        UpdateServices-RSAT            Available
            [ ] API and PowerShell cmdlets              UpdateServices-API             Available
            [ ] User Interface Management Console       UpdateServices-UI              Available
        [ ] Active Directory Certificate Services Tools RSAT-ADCS                      Available
            [ ] Certification Authority Management T... RSAT-ADCS-Mgmt                 Available
            [ ] Online Responder Tools                  RSAT-Online-Responder          Available
        [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Servi... RSAT-ADRMS                     Available
        [ ] DHCP Server Tools                           RSAT-DHCP                      Available
        [ ] DNS Server Tools                            RSAT-DNS-Server                Available
        [ ] Fax Server Tools                            RSAT-Fax                       Available
        [ ] File Services Tools                         RSAT-File-Services             Available
            [ ] DFS Management Tools                    RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con              Available
            [ ] File Server Resource Manager Tools      RSAT-FSRM-Mgmt                 Available
            [ ] Services for Network File System Man... RSAT-NFS-Admin                 Available
            [ ] Share and Storage Management Tool       RSAT-CoreFile-Mgmt             Available
        [ ] Network Policy and Access Services Tools    RSAT-NPAS                      Available
        [ ] Print and Document Services Tools           RSAT-Print-Services            Available
        [ ] Remote Access Management Tools              RSAT-RemoteAccess              Available
            [ ] Remote Access GUI and Command-Line T... RSAT-RemoteAccess-Mgmt         Available
            [ ] Remote Access module for Windows Pow... RSAT-RemoteAccess-Po...        Available
        [ ] Volume Activation Tools                     RSAT-VA-Tools                  Available
        [ ] Windows Deployment Services Tools           WDS-AdminPack                  Available
[ ] RPC over HTTP Proxy                                 RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy            Available
[ ] Simple TCP/IP Services                              Simple-TCPIP                   Available
[X] SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support                   FS-SMB1                        Installed
[ ] SMB Bandwidth Limit                                 FS-SMBBW                       Available
[ ] SMTP Server                                         SMTP-Server                    Available
[ ] SNMP Service                                        SNMP-Service                   Available
    [ ] SNMP WMI Provider                               SNMP-WMI-Provider              Available
[ ] Telnet Client                                       Telnet-Client                  Available
[ ] Telnet Server                                       Telnet-Server                  Available
[ ] TFTP Client                                         TFTP-Client                    Available
[X] User Interfaces and Infrastructure                  User-Interfaces-Infra          Installed
    [X] Graphical Management Tools and Infrastructure   Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra          Installed
    [ ] Desktop Experience                              Desktop-Experience             Available
    [X] Server Graphical Shell                          Server-Gui-Shell               Installed
[ ] Windows Biometric Framework                         Biometric-Framework            Available
[ ] Windows Feedback Forwarder                          WFF                            Available
[ ] Windows Identity Foundation 3.5                     Windows-Identity-Fou...        Available
[ ] Windows Internal Database                           Windows-Internal-Dat...        Available
[X] Windows PowerShell                                  PowerShellRoot                 Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 4.0                          PowerShell                     Installed
    [ ] Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine                   PowerShell-V2                    Removed
    [ ] Windows PowerShell Desired State Configurati... DSC-Service                    Available
    [X] Windows PowerShell ISE                          PowerShell-ISE                 Installed
    [ ] Windows PowerShell Web Access                   WindowsPowerShellWeb...        Available
[ ] Windows Process Activation Service                  WAS                            Available
    [ ] Process Model                                   WAS-Process-Model              Available
    [ ] .NET Environment 3.5                            WAS-NET-Environment            Available
    [ ] Configuration APIs                              WAS-Config-APIs                Available
[ ] Windows Search Service                              Search-Service                 Available
[ ] Windows Server Backup                               Windows-Server-Backup          Available
[ ] Windows Server Migration Tools                      Migration                      Available
[ ] Windows Standards-Based Storage Management          WindowsStorageManage...        Available
[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                                Windows-TIFF-IFilter           Available
[ ] WinRM IIS Extension                                 WinRM-IIS-Ext                  Available
[ ] WINS Server                                         WINS                           Available
[ ] Wireless LAN Service                                Wireless-Networking            Available
[X] WoW64 Support                                       WoW64-Support                  Installed
[ ] XPS Viewer                                          XPS-Viewer                     Available
```

Comment: This looks like the output of a Powershell script. Any chance you could provide that?

Comment: @CBauer it's a Powershell command: C:\ Get-WindowsFeature

Answer (score 0):

Run `Get-WindowsFeature` in Powershell on your server.