# feature-names for windows-server-2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

I found following link in the website where i can find the names of features for Windows Server 2012 R2.

[PowerShell - What Feature names can I use on Windows Server 2012 R2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/801127/powershell-what-feature-names-can-i-use-on-windows-server-2012-r2)

Can any one help me finding similar mapping of features and names for Windows servers 2012 and 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Get-WindowsFeature will list the available features